# I have a CSV and want to update it with values from another CSV. What is the most efficient way to do this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have this CSV:

```
      Name  Species    Country
0    Hobbes   Tiger       U.S.
1  SherKhan   Tiger      India
2   Rescuer   Mouse  Australia
3    Mickey   Mouse       U.S.

And I have a second CSV: 
   Continent     Countries Unnamed: 2 Unnamed: 3 Unnamed: 4
0  North America          U.S.     Mexico  Guatemala   Honduras
1           Asia         India      China      Nepal        NaN
2      Australia     Australia        NaN        NaN        NaN
3         Africa  South Africa   Botswana   Zimbabwe        NaN

I want to use the second CSV to update the first file so that the output is:
      Name  Species        Country
0    Hobbes   Tiger  North America
1  SherKhan   Tiger           Asia 
2   Rescuer   Mouse      Australia
3    Mickey   Mouse  North America
```

So far this the closest I have gotten:

```
import pandas as pd

# Import my data. 
data = pd.read_csv('Continents.csv')
Animals = pd.read_csv('Animals.csv')
Animalsdf = pd.DataFrame(Animals)

# Transpose my data from horizontal to vertical. 
data1 = data.T

# Clean my data and update my header with the first column. 
data1.columns = data1.iloc[0]

# Drop now duplicated data. 
data1.drop(data1.index[[0]], inplace = True)
# Build the dictionary. 
data_dict = {col: list(data1[col]) for col in data1.columns}

# Update my csv. 
Animals['Country'] = Animals['Country'].map(data_dict)

print ('Animals')
```

This results in a dictionary that has lists as its values and therefore i just get NaN out:

```
      Name  Species                     Country
0    Hobbes   Tiger                         NaN
1  SherKhan   Tiger                         NaN
2   Rescuer    Mole  [Australia, nan, nan, nan]
3    Mickey    Mole                         NaN
```

I've tried flipping from list to tuples and this doesn't work. Have tried multiple ways to pull in the dictionary etc. I am just out of ideas.

Sorry if the code is super junky. I'm learning this as I go. Figured a project was the best way to learn a new language. Didn't think it would be this difficult.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I need to be able to use the code so that when I get multiple reference CSVs, I can update my data with new keys. Hope this is clear.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One intuitive solution is to use a dictionary mapping. Data from @WillMonge.

`pd.DataFrame.itertuples` works by producing namedtuples, but they may also be referenced using numeric indexers.

```
# create mapping dictionary
d = {}
for row in df.itertuples():
    d.update(dict.fromkeys(filter(None, row[2:]), row[1]))

# apply mapping dictionary
data['Continent'] = data['Country'].map(d)

print(data)

  Country  name Continent
0   China     2      Asia
1   China     5      Asia
2  Canada     9   America
3   Egypt     0    Africa
4  Mexico     3   America
```

Comment: Thank you! I am testing this one as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should use DictReader and DictWriter. You can learn how to use them by below link.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: I believe that for his needs, `pandas` is a much better way to read the data from the csv files

Answer (score 0):

Here is an update of your code, I have tried to add comments to explain

```
import pandas as pd

# Read data in (read_csv also returns a DataFrame directly)
data = pd.DataFrame({'name': [2, 5, 9, 0, 3], 'Country': ['China', 'China', 'Canada', 'Egypt', 'Mexico']})
df = pd.DataFrame({'Continent': ['Asia', 'America', 'Africa'],
                   'Country1': ['China', 'Mexico', 'Egypt'],
                   'Country2': ['Japan', 'Canada', None],
                   'Country3': ['Thailand', None, None ]})

# Unstack to get a row for each country (remove the continent rows)
premap_df = pd.DataFrame(df.unstack('Continent').drop('Continent')).dropna().reset_index()
premap_df.columns = ['_', 'continent_key', 'Country']

# Merge the continent back based on the continent_key (old row number)
map_df = pd.merge(premap_df, df[['Continent']], left_on='continent_key', right_index=True)[['Continent', 'Country']]

# Merge with the data now 
pd.merge(data, map_df, on='Country')
```

For further reference, Wes McKinney's *Python for Data Analysis* ([here](http://opencarts.org/sachlaptrinh/pdf/28232.pdf) is a pdf version I found online) is one of the best books out there for learning `pandas`

Comment: Thanks for the advice! This seems to be a good solution moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create buckets and run conditions:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Hobbes','SherKhan','Rescuer','Mickey'], 'Species':['Tiger','Tiger','Mouse','Mouse'],'Country':['U.S.','India','Australia','U.S.']})

North_America = ['U.S.', 'Mexico', 'Guatemala', 'Honduras'] 
Asia = ['India', 'China', 'Nepal']
Australia = ['Australia']
Africa = ['South Africa', 'Botswana', 'Zimbabwe']

conditions = [
(df['Country'].isin(North_America)),
(df['Country'].isin(Asia)),
(df['Country'].isin(Australia)),
(df['Country'].isin(Africa))
]
choices = [
'North America',
'Asia',
'Australia',
'Africa'
]
df['Continent'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default = np.nan)
df
```

Comment: The buckets are a good idea. If I can auto build them from the csv instead, it would be perfect but thank you for the good suggestion.

Comment: @TheMagicRaj you can create lists simply by using `list(df['col'])` this will create your buckets down the column